# Python 3.7 - Fast way to concatenate strings and write them to disk

Tags: python, io

Is there a better implementation for:

```
file = open("./myFile.txt","w+")
for doc in allDocuments: #around 35 million documents
    file.write(str(doc.number)+"\r\n")
f.close()
```

Currently this implementation is taking 20sec per file

Comment: You are calling `.write` millions of times. It would be more efficient to call it fewer times, ideally once.

Comment: Using `w+` is an error for text files.

Comment: @Daniel why is that? can you please expand?

Comment: The `+` is for reading and writing with random access, which is not practical for text files.

Comment: @Leonardo `w+` opens a file for reading _and writing_, whereas `w` opens only for writing.

Comment: @I thought `w+` was write and overwrite

Comment: `w+` lets you read and write from the same handle. You can always use `seek` to change where the next write occurs. *All* writes overwrite whatever previous content was at the current position; you can't just insert new bytes into the middle of a file.

Comment: How much is there to write in total? Is simply creating the entire string first a viable option?

Comment: @chepner - But its only safe to `seek(0)` because of the difference in size between unencoded bytes and encoded characters (and the buffering python does for the encoding). Maybe we should say its _usually_ an error to open a text file in "w+". In OP's case, the file isn't seeked or read so the rule of least privilege applies.

Comment: That's what I (very indirectly) alluded to with "can't just insert new bytes into the middle", but that ignores the possibility not just of overwriting more than you meant but of starting a write in the middle of a (e.g.) UTF-8 byte.

Comment: @Leonardo - "w" always truncates the file. Add an "+" to also make it readable. The "+" is only useful in the rare case that you want to rewind the file and read it from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could buffer the output and write in blocks:

```
with open("./myFile.txt", "w") as output:
    lines = []
    for doc in allDocuments:
        lines.append(f"{doc.number}\r\n")
        if len(lines) > 1000:
            output.writelines(lines)
            lines = []
    output.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Great answer.  I would also experiment with different numbers.  The answer of 1,000, try 10,000, 100,000, etc. and see which works best for you. :)

Comment: So, python `open` returns a buffered file object already. Not sure if this is necessary

Comment: Since files are already buffered, it's not the case that every call to `write` actually incurs disk I/O. All this does is trade a call to `output.write` for a call to `lines.append`.

Comment: So, it's probably easier to just modify the buffering parameter, which defaults to line buffering for text files, which doesn't seem ideal in this particular case

Comment: I agree with @chepner. And with that, I believe his answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60308140/5666087) is superior.

Comment: @chepner if you can't tell the difference between `output.write` and `lines.append` I'd suggest you to replicate the original question and test it for yourself. I consider this to be a better approach than yours bellow because it's ALOT more memory friendlier. Your suggestion is so memory-unfriendly that I can't even run it on my default size container (1 core, 512ram)

Comment: I may have been mistaken in my belief that `writelines` would write each line as it reads it from the generator; I will check that. However, I never said that `output.write` and `lines.append` were the *same*, just that for each call to `output.write` you eliminate you just replace it with another function call. The total number of calls hasn't decreased.

Comment: I wrote a generator `allDocuments` that simply yielded the number `5` 350,000,000 times, then called `f.writelines(f'{doc}\r\n' for doc in allDocuments())`. Its memory usage is constant around 5MB. You didn't use a list comprehension instead of a generator expression, did you? It also completed in under 3 minutes.

Comment: @Leonardo @chepner When using `open()` with a text mode, it returns a [`TextIOWrapper`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44c690112d96a81fe02433de7900a4f8f9457012/Lib/_pyio.py#L1966) object, a child of [`TextIOBase`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44c690112d96a81fe02433de7900a4f8f9457012/Lib/_pyio.py#L1814), itself a child of [`IOBase`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44c690112d96a81fe02433de7900a4f8f9457012/Lib/_pyio.py#L313) where [`readlines()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44c690112d96a81fe02433de7900a4f8f9457012/Lib/_pyio.py#L593) is defined.

Comment: Since neither of those two descendants appear to override the method, the definition in `IOBase` is used, which is simply `self._checkClosed(); for line in lines: self.write(line)`. (I've spent very little time looking at Python's inner workings, so I hope I was in the right place)

Answer (score 3):

The I/O isn't really the problem, nor can you do anything useful about it: the file object and the operating system will both be doing some form of buffering. What you *can* do something about is the number of method calls you make.

```
with open("./myFile.txt", "w", newline='\r\n') as f:
    f.writelines(f'{doc.number}\n' for doc in allDocuments)
```

The `writelines` method takes an iterable of strings to write to the file.  (The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) says "list", but it seems to be speaking of lists, not `list`s; a generator expression seems to work as well.) The generator expression produces each line on demand for `writelines`.

---

Here's a test:

```
import random

def allDocuments():
    for i in range(35_000_000):
        yield random.randint(0, 100)

with open("tmp.txt", "w", newline='\r\n') as f:
    f.writelines(f'{doc}\n' for doc in allDocuments())
```

It completed in 75 seconds (most of that due to the repeated calls to `random.randint`), using less than 6MB of memory. (Replacing the call to `random.randint` with a constant value dropped the running time to under 30 seconds.)

Comment: +1. the use of a generator in `file.writelines` has been proposed on stack overflow in the past by the mighty martijn pieters https://stackoverflow.com/a/44560826/5666087